# Moving APNS to Production with app that is alreay in appstore

Tags: iphone, app-store, apple-push-notifications

I have a application in the app store, the current Distribution certificate was issued before I configured APNS. I want to build a update that will include APNS.

My question is do I need to revoke and re-issue the Distribution certificate for APNS to work or is that just included? I know that I had to do that with the provisioning profile in order to use APNS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to download the newly configured cert, build the app using that and re-submit to the appstore :)